# Google API Web Client Oauth 2 redirect uri for aws ec2 uri

Tags: amazon-ec2, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I have developed a google analytics management app using google API's and oauth2. I could add localhots:8001 successfully in redirect URI.

Now I have deployed my app in aws ec2 instance. I need to add my aws ec2 instance domain name as redirect uri. It is not taking my ec2 domain name. It says domain must be added in authorized domain list.

I would need to know what are the basic steps to figure out such situations.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to add a redirect uri is if you own the domain.  Then you can point the domain to to your server (ec2 address).

If you already own the domain, then see the process for pointing the domain to a server in your domain registrar.

Then use that url for redirect after auth.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So there is no other way to add my own custom domain without verification. Any way around to this?

Comment: No a redirect uri must point to a domain you own.  You cant just point it anywhere.